# Show that some endomorphsm is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an endomorphism $f:V \rightarrow V$ on an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, prove that if there is $v \in V-\{0\}$ such that $f^2(v)=-v$, then $f$ is not diagonalizable.

Comment: As soon as $V\neq 0$; there is always $v\in V\smallsetminus \{0\}$.  You're missing some part of your question...?

Comment: It means that v is not the zero vector

Comment: I know what it means. I am saying that if $V$ is a nonzero space, there is always a nonzero vector.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the proof.

Comment: Read your question again, please.

Comment: Oh sorry now I see, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I'm putting the solution. If A is a matrix for f in some basis, then $A^2v=-v$. If $A$ is in diagonal form, $A^2$ has only non-negative entries on the diagonal.

Comment: Nice solution. =)